# Comparison between normal glm and glm.nb regression with quadratic term?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, bias, negative-binomial-distribution, quadratic-form

Let's say I have a function to simulate data for negative binomial regression:

```
simnegbin = function(X, beta, alpha) {
lambda = exp(1 + X %*% beta)
y=NULL
for (j in 1:length(lambda)) y = c(y,rnbinom(1,mu = lambda[j],size = alpha))
return(y)
}
```

And I call that function like this:

```
set.seed(123)
x1 = rnorm(100)
X = matrix(c(x1,x1^2), ncol = 2) # data with quadratic effect
beta = c(0.5,-0.5) # coefficients one with negative sign
alpha = 1
y = simnegbin(X, beta, alpha)
```

And then I fit two models to this simulated data.

```
NB = MASS::glm.nb(y ~ X)
Normal = glm(y ~ X)
```

And look at the resulting coefficients. Nothing too strange. The model assuming a normal distribution is slightly higher, but not too bad.

```
coef(NB)
coef(Normal)
```

Normal:

```
(Intercept)      X1          X2 
  2.3997424   0.4019599  -0.5234614
```

NB:

```
(Intercept)      X1          X2 
  0.8992080   0.3573460  -0.4023558
```

But then when I simply switch the sign to positive of the coefficient in a second call to the function:

```
X = matrix(c(x1,x1^2), ncol = 2)
beta = c(0.5,0.5) # coefficients with positive sign
alpha = 1
y = simnegbin(X, beta, alpha)
```

And then I fit two models using the same simulated data.

```
NB = MASS::glm.nb(y ~ X)
Normal = glm(y ~ X)

coef(Normal)
coef(NB)
```

Normal:

```
(Intercept)      X1          X2 
    1.342937    3.162534    4.130669 # Biased term
```

NB:

```
(Intercept)     X1          X2 
0.9097782   0.2905278   0.4587727
```

The quadratic coefficient of the glm assuming the normal distribution is **super biased**.

Does anyone have any intuition about why this would be?